# Date type format compare with varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have
`declare @date varchar(6)= '202206'` ,
And I need to compare with original date format type is date (yyyy-mm-dd) and update all 202206's data

I use code below

```
declare @date varchar(6)= '202206';
select *
from xxx
where 
   [DateTime] >= left(@date,4) + '-' + Right(@date,2) + '-01' and 
   [DateTime] <= left(@date,4) + '-' + Right(@date,2) + '-31'
```

But June doesn't have 31 days so it will error, how can I edit it?

Comment: Use proper data datatypes and proper date functions?

Comment: What is the data type of the `[DateTime]` column?

Comment: @Zhorov [DateTime]  is date

Comment: Naming a column after its data type really should be avoided, it doesn't contain any meaning - you wouldn't name an ID column `Integer` I would hope? What if you had several date columns...

Answer (score 2):

The `EOMONTH()` function is an option (I assume the `[DateTime]` column is a `date` column).

```
DECLARE @date varchar(6)= '202206';

SELECT *
FROM xxx
WHERE 
   [DateTime] >= CONVERT(date, @date + '01', 112) AND 
   [DateTime] <= EOMONTH(CONVERT(date, @date + '01', 112))
```

Comment: @Lily, if you think that this or any other answer is the best solution to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the datepart function

```
DECLARE @date varchar(6)= '202206';

SELECT *
FROM   xxx
WHERE  datepart(year, [DateTime]) >= datepart(year, convert(date, @date + '01'))
AND    datepart(month, [DateTime]) <= datepart(month, convert(date, @date + '01'))
```

This would be a lot easier if you have option to make other variables

```
DECLARE @date varchar(6) = '202206';

declare @fulldate date = @date + '01'

SELECT *
FROM   xxx
WHERE  datepart(year, [DateTime]) >= datepart(year, @fulldate)
AND    datepart(month, [DateTime]) <= datepart(month, @fulldate)
```

or even

```
declare @year int = 2022
declare @month int = 6

SELECT *
FROM   xxx
WHERE  datepart(year, [DateTime]) >= @year
AND    datepart(month, [DateTime]) <= @month
```